# Emacs LSP server inside docker container hanging on startup

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, docker, python-lsp-server

I'm trying to use emacs lsp and pyright server with docker. I'm trying to use [custom containers as explained here.](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-docker#custom-language-server-containers)
I've managed to setup [this super simple test project](https://github.com/Freder211/emacs-lsp-docker-test). The lsp server starts, however I think that emacs doesn't communicate well with it. When I run `lsp-describe-session` it says that the lsp server is starting, but it never moves on from this state (see the screenshot).

[image]

I've been struggling all day long to make this work. I also tried to follow the instructions from [this page](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/docker-integration/) but I didn't accomplish much. I couldn't find much resources online about this so I'm asking here.